# Consuming messages from RabbitMQ: [amqp] Detected TCP connection failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabbitmq, amqp

The following Rails rake task works on my Rails development system. But after deploying to
the Rails production environment it fails.

```
rake pform_queue:receive RAILS_ENV=production
Stop with Ctrl+c
Waiting for application forms ...
[amqp] Detected TCP connection failure
```

Telnet shows that RabbitMQ is listening on the default port:

```
telnet localhost 5672
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
rtyr
fghtryr
AMQP    Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Below the code of the rake task.

```
 desc "Wait for application forms from pform"
  task :receive  => :environment do
    require "amqp"

    EventMachine.run do
      connection = AMQP.connect(:host => 'localhost')
      channel  = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
      queue    = channel.queue("pform.applicationforms", :durable => true)

      puts "Stop with Ctrl+c"
      puts "Waiting for application forms ..."

      queue.subscribe do |payload|
        puts "#{Time.now} Received a message"
      end
    end
  end
```

We use apache/passenger in production, but I thought that this is of no consequence for rake tasks.

```
amq-protocol (1.8.0)
amqp (1.1.0)
"RabbitMQ","2.5.0"
```

I have now upgraded to:

```
amq-protocol (1.9.2
amqp (1.3.0)
"RabbitMQ","3.2.4"
```

which has not solved my problem

1026 is the pid of RabbitMQ

```
netstat -plane | grep 1026
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42325           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      107        6881        1026/beam.smp   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34438         127.0.0.1:4369          ESTABLISHED 107        6883        1026/beam.smp   
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      107        6912        1026/beam.smp
```

Logging details:

```
bundle exec rake pform_queue:receive RAILS_ENV=production
[amqp] Detected TCP connection failure
Failed to connect {:host=>"127.0.0.1", :port=>5672, :user=>"guest", :pass=>"guest",   :auth_mechanism=>"PLAIN", :vhost=>"/", :timeout=>0.3, :logging=>false, :ssl=>false, :frame_max=>131072, :heartbeat=>0, :on_tcp_connection_failure=># <Proc:0x00000005c3c968@/home/calm/wwwshare/registration/releases/20140310035559/lib/tasks /pform_receive_mq.rake:15>, :on_possible_authentication_failure=># <Proc:0x00000005c3c940@/home/calm/wwwshare/registration/releases/20140310035559/lib/tasks/pform_receive_mq.rake:23>}


/var/log/rabbitmq# tail -f rabbit@Calm-Integration.log
=INFO REPORT==== 10-Mar-2014::08:56:32 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.2293.0> (127.0.0.1:56421 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 10-Mar-2014::08:56:35 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.2304.0> (127.0.0.1:56422 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=WARNING REPORT==== 10-Mar-2014::08:56:35 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.2304.0> (127.0.0.1:56422 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly

=WARNING REPORT==== 10-Mar-2014::08:56:35 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.2293.0> (127.0.0.1:56421 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly
```

To repeat again: The problem occurs only on the production system, not in development!
I am quite stuck with this.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I have switched from the 'amqp' gem to the 'bunny' gem. Bunny does not depend on EventMachine. It seems to be easier to use, at least it is now working.

config/initializers/amqp.rb

```
# http://rubybunny.info/articles/connecting.html#connecting_in_web_applications_ruby_on_rails_sinatra_etc
if defined?(PhusionPassenger) # otherwise it breaks rake commands if you put this in an initializer
  PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
    if forked
      # We’re in a smart spawning mode
      # Now is a good time to connect to RabbitMQ
      $rabbitmq_connection = Bunny.new
      $rabbitmq_connection.start
      $rabbitmq_channel = $rabbitmq_connection.create_channel
    end
  end
else
  $rabbitmq_connection = Bunny.new
  $rabbitmq_connection.start
  $rabbitmq_channel = $rabbitmq_connection.create_channel

end
```